# Minimizing then restoring Terminal window in High Sierra focuses on first rather than current tab

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, high-sierra

Just noticed this after upgrading, and it's not a huge deal but it does get annoying when constantly minimizing/restoring Terminal windows.

The gist: regardless of which tab you're currently working in, minimizing then restoring will always set the focus to the first (left-most) tab.

Is there any way to revert to the original MacOS behavior, where restoring a minimized Terminal window preserves the current tab?

Comment: Observing the same glitch after a fresh install of macOS `10.13.3`. Previously used an updated version which worked fine. I noticed this just happens if you restore from the dock AND in your system preferences for the dock `Minimize windows into application icon` is activated.